# Unlock Asset Account on GNUCash by updating placeholder checkbox

Tags: gnucash

In GNUCash I am looking for the account options that would allow me to turn off the placeholder checkbox in order to update an asset account (told they are under preferences but cannot find them there).  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Right click on the account in the accounts list and choose "edit account", it's there.

Comment: Thank you - found it!!